# In which case rabbits give noise?

Tags: rabbits, vocalizations

My female rabbit gives noise if she is grooming her back. It sounds like her breath gets out because of to small space for air in her lungs. Like a human with a big belly making noise by getting the hands to the feets.

Now I am worried if she has pain, because I heared, rabbits gave no noise, only in big pain.

When do rabbits make noise? Are there reasons not connected with danger or pain?

Comment: Can you post a video of her making this sound?

Comment: I have none, but I will do when I have made one. My focus for "long time use" of this question lay more on the "noise without pain" part :)

Comment: In that case it might be a duplicate of this post https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/2264/13 but the more specific noise you are talking about is not covered there.  I am pretty sure I know what the sound is, and that it is not a problem, but a video would help.  My rabbit makes sounds like this when grooming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of noises you describe but my bunny makes noises when eating sometimes (and when he sees me filling his plate with food) so I guess noises sometimes come from other things and not only pain.

Here is my bunny making noises when eating:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JOcedLpV8ZA

Comment: That little noise at the end of the video, my rabbit(s) will make it when grooming. Sometimes it lasts a few seconds.  If that is the sound the OP is asking about, I agree it is not a problem.

Comment: Yep.... mine is doing it for years.

Comment: Thank you for the video. The sound is similar, like air is pressed out.