# My bunny is making a new noise I’ve never heard before and I was wondering if anyone has ever heard a similar noise from another bunny?

Tags: health, rabbits, diseases, veterinarian, upper-respiratory-disease

My 3-month old lionhead bunny has started making a new noise. She previously was ill with the snuffles, completed a course of antibiotic. She was never very ill with the snuffles just very sneezy and a little bit of clear discharge from her noise. When she was sick and even now she is acting the same way, eating, pooping/peeing, and playing like normal. I’ve attempted to attach a video of the sound. It’s sort of like a rattle of chitter noise. She’s not grinding her teeth or purring. It’s not a constant noise and happens randomly. She is having audible breathing, I’m just trying to figure out if she is sick. TIA.

New bunny mom!

https://share.icloud.com/photos/06809WSg406eJnQ0nt8RloMig#Brighton

Question: Could noisy breathing be a sign of illness? And if yes, for which?

Comment: welcome to pets.SE :) please add the video it would be very helpful. you could add a link to the video. in general rabbits do not make noise. but if there was something with the breathing system, then noises are a sign to look closer on the health. did the vet do an x-ray before the antibiotics? because sneezing and other signs of a cold are often caused by problems with the teeth. then antibiotics do not help on the long term.

Comment: have a look to this question about general noise of rabbits: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17105/my-rabbit-is-making-this-weird-noise-is-something-wrong?r=SearchResults

Comment: and here is a second post about general noise: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/25901/in-which-case-rabbits-give-noise?r=SearchResults

Comment: I just added a link to the video, hopefully it works.

Comment: yes it works. None of my bunnies has made such a noise. I could not decide, what it causes. You should search for an rabbit experiences vet (rabbits are no part of a "normal"/"general" vet study) and let check your rabbit up. In worst case there is an issue with the teeth that cause infection in the near by nose and eye parts. Teeth problems are often hidden and could cause a slowly starving rabbit. They could be only full excluded by an x-ray, because the vet could not see all inside the mouth from outside (caused in the architecture of bunnies bodys).

Comment: A second thing that makes breathing so hard for rabbits is, that they have only a very small connection between breathing pipe and mouth. In fact it is nearly not possible for them to breath through the mouth like humans. So a full nose is more painful for them, than for a human.